# C++ how to use an unitialized smart pointer

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I am not totally expert with C++ and I need to declare an unitialized smart pointer into my class and using it in a method inherited from a super class for which I cannot modify the source code, because it's part of a precompiled library.

The situation is as such:

```
class myClass: public xNS::aClass
{
   private:
      xClass& mysmp;

   public:
      myClass();
      virtual ~myClass();

      /* method inherited */
      void foo(bClass& xsmp);
}
```

And this is what I would like to do in the method foo:

```
void myClass::foo(bClass& xsmp)
{
   mysmp = xsmp;
}
```

I tried to solve using a member initializer list as so:

```
myClass()::myClass() : mysmp(NULL)
{
   /* ... */
}
```

But I understand it's not possible since the compiler returns an error..
How can I solve my problem ?

If can be helpful, I am using g++.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: That's not a smart pointer, it's a reference. And you *can't* leave a reference undefined, nor can you change it later.

Comment: You seem to want to initialize the pointer to null rather than keep it uninitialized. But your class doesn't contain any pointers smart or otherwise. It does contain a reference `mysmp`. References may not be uninitialized or set to null.

Comment: It's also confusing that you name the parameter mysmp in the method declaration, but then name it xsmp in the method's implementation, and then try to use mysmp in the method without defining it in that scope. I don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: You have to initialize `mysmp` in the constructor of `myClass` or use an ordinary(`*`) or smart pointer(`http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/`) instead.

Comment: I tried to initialize it as foobar suggest. It does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's clear something up:

xClass& mysmp isn't a pointer. It isn't even a smart pointer, for that matter. The ampersand (&) after a type in a variable declaration means it is a *reference*.

xClass& means that mysmp **must** *refer* to an *existing* xClass instance. It may not refer to NULL. It also cannot refer to nothing; it must be initialized with something to refer to. Furthermore, references may not be changed to refer to a different instance after they have already been assigned.

That being said, if you still wish to use a reference, you can initialize it in the constructor initializer list like so:

```
myClass::myClass(xClass& xsmp) : mysmp(xsmp)
{
   /* ... */
}
```

If it makes sense in your design that mysmp may be null, you could use a raw or (preferably) **smart pointer**, like *std::unique_ptr*

```
// ...
std::unique_ptr<xClass> mysmp;
// ...
```

The unique_ptr is initialized to point to nothing (nullptr) by default, so there's no need to explicitly set it to a null value in the myClass constructor.

Comment: : mysmp(nullptr) is redundant

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that paulm :) I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need a variable whose value is a reference. Fortunately [reference_wrapper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) exists for precisely this purpose.

Comment: C++11 is just full of surprises. Unfortunately it's not a perfect replacement for a reference, you can't override `operator.`.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain so the answer can be fixed/improved?

Comment: The asker's understanding of references appears to be flawed, and I don't feel this answer contributes to a better understanding. While reference_wrapper is useful in certain cases, I don't see how it applies to this one at all. Could you elaborate on why or how it could be used to help the asker?

Comment: The asker is confusing smart pointers with references. What they seem to want is a retargetable reference, which is exactly what a reference_wrapper is. The OP wants a variable whose value is a reference.

Comment: A reference_wrapper must be initialized to refer to something though, no? One can't be left uninitialized, as far as I know.

Comment: @AtlasC1 Yes. You can use things like `boost::optional` if needed.